# Is a nested pure function still a pure function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, immutability

By definition, a **Pure Function** is pure if:

- Given the same input, will always return the same output.
- Produces no side effects.
- Relies on no external state.

So this is a pure function:

```
function foo(x) {
  return x * 2;
}

foo(1) // 2
foo(2) // 4
foo(3) // 6
```

And this would be a pure function as well (in JavaScript context)

```
Math.floor(x);

Math.floor(1.1); // 1
Math.floor(1.2); // 1
Math.floor(2.2); // 2
```

The question: **if we combine these 2 pure function, would it still be considered as a pure function?**

```
// Nested with Math library
function bar(x) {
  return Math.floor(x);
}

// Nested even deeper
function foobar(x) {
  return foo(Math.floor(x));
}
```

Obviously, it still always return the same output given the same input without side effects, but does calling a function from other context (scope) break the law for "*Relies on no external state*"?

Comment: I guess as long as `foo` doesn't rely on any external state and doesn't change its behaviour based on any external state `foobar` will still be a pure function.

Comment: yes, allowing combination does not break the fact that a function is pure.

Comment: In my understanding its not a pure function now. Function which does `Math.floor` will become a utility function. Now if I change this utility function, all subscribers will be effected. Do utility function is pure but subscribers are not as they depend on utility.

Comment: So even if a function relies on "external functions", such as 3rd-party libraries, it's still not treated as an "external state" ?

Comment: @Rajesh that's exactly what I am concerned about

Comment: As long as your third party functions don't use anything which is not in their own scope they are pure, and by that logic your foobar is too.

Comment: @kavare I guess deceze's answer clarifies it. There were gaps in my understanding

Comment: @Rajesh As long as `moment` is not using any variable which is not in its current scope, your method which is using `moment` apis will not become impure by it.

Comment: @Rajesh *"if I change this utility function, all subscribers will be effected"* - this is true. But then again, this is the case with any and all changes. If you change a function signature, callers will be screwed. If you change a synchronous function to an asynchronous function, callers will be screwed. Purity isn't a very special case.

Comment: @Rajesh: *Now if I change this utility function, all subscribers will be effected*. You should distinguish between changes to the utility function made: (1) Prior to compile time and (2) During runtime. A function invoking a utility function that could undergo changes during runtime would not be a pure function because that could result in a different `return value` for the same set of `arguments` during runtime.

Comment: @rabbitco Thanks for explanation. I have already highlighted that there were gaps in my understanding and they were rectified by deceze's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

External *state* is different from *external code*. If pure functions couldn't use external code, then there pretty much would be no such thing as a pure function at all. Even if all your function does is `x * 2`, in (many) pure functional languages even `*` *is a function*. So even this simple function cannot avoid calling other functions.

Function definitions are more or less just syntax details. You could inline the function body of external functions into a longer expression. E.g.:

```
function foo(a, b) {
    return bar(a) + bar(b);
}

function bar(x) {
    return x * 2;
}
```

is identical to:

```
function foo(a, b) {
    return a * 2 + b * 2;
}
```

The only difference is reusability of code snippets and/or readability and maintainability. Not purity.

A function is pure if it doesn't cause side effects or is influenced by side effects/state outside itself. It stays pure as long as all the code it calls also conforms to that rule.

Comment: Thank you for you example for multiplication I think it demystify a lot of things. 

However, one selling point for Pure Function is that they are always `independent`, so it's easy to pull and plug between different code modules.  If a Pure Function does allow an underlying dependency for a function coming from else where (i.e. not pass in as an argument), how would the consumer for that function know there's a implicit dependency?

Comment: That's a matter of how dependencies are handled in your language of choice. "Pull and plug" hopefully doesn't mean *copy and paste*, right? What you mean is that you `import some_module` and use `some_module.some_function()`, or however it works exactly in your language of choice. That leaves `some_module` entirely free to lay out its code however it likes, including dependencies.

Comment: Then it doesn't really matter what *source code* exactly is needed for `some_function`. There's little difference between needing to copy and paste (no no!) or install/import one function/module/dependency and a whole bunch of them. You simply need to have access to all the relevant source code if you want to call that function. That's an entirely different concern than whether the function *behaves* purely or not.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right to assume that "reuse" of a function should comes from package import level instead of simple copy & paste :)
Thumbs up.

Comment: And even if it was copy and paste: what's the difference between copy and pasting one giant function or several smaller functions which all belong together? Again: it's a mere syntactical difference.

Answer (score 1):

> Does calling a function from other context (scope) break the law for
>   "Relies on no external state"?

Not if the link between `arguments` and `return value` is still pure.

A pure function maps an input (`arguments`) to an output (`return value`) in a way that can be predicted with an 100 % accuracy solely based on the `arguments` and without containing any other code than that necessary to produce the `return value`.

### How to test whether a function is pure

You can apply this simple test to determine whether it is pure:

```
function multiplication (integer) {

var result = 2 * integer;
return result;
}

console.log(multiplication(4)) // 8
```

What will always be true about `multiplication(integer)` is that you in your code can simply replace a call to it by the `return value` it produces for a given `argument`. That is in stead of writing `multiplication(4)` in your code you could just write `8`. This test fails as soon as the function becomes impure:

```
function multiplicationImpure (integer) {

    var result = 2 * integer;
    console.log (result);
    return result;
    }

console.log(multiplicationImpure(4)) // 8 8
```

Now if you where to replace `multiplicationImpure(4)` with `8` in your code it would no longer be the same: there would be missing one `8` in the output to the console. Likewise simply putting `8` in your code would be a problem if some external state could result in another return value than `8` for the argument `2` .

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that, in  JavaScript,

```
function foo(x) {
  return Math.floor(x);
}
```

is not a pure function. I would agree if `Math` was only a namespace. But in JavaScript (AFAIK) it is a full featured mutable object. Therefor `foo` relies on the state of the external `Math` object and is not pure. One way to make it pure would be to use

```
const floor = Math.floor;
function foo(x) {
  return floor(x);
}
```

That way, `foo` would not depends on the state of the `Math` object and is pure.